# DataCell overflows with column with multiple text widgets [dataTable]

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-widget

i'm using dataTable to show some data on my app , and i'm facing the problem DataCell overflows with column with multiple text widgets , row height doesn't adjust based on content height , because of fix  row heigh , i need to set row heigh dynamic , how can i do it ? :(

Link Issue flutter github : [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70510)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

DataTable(
columnSpacing: 38.0,
dataRowHeight: 80, )
Just Give the data row height in DataTable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).